# If you laid a perfectly level beam on a centered scale and an off-center scale, what weight would each scale measure?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, weight

Imagine you laid a metal beam on a scale so that the scale was in the center of the beam, so it would be balanced and not fall off. The scale would display the full weight of the beam. But what if you put a second scale that is the same exact height as the first scale under one of the ends of the beam? Would both scales display the full weight or would each scale display half the weight or something else?

Comment: You should edit your question headline. It gives the impression that you mean 2 scales each at one end of the beam.

Answer (score 1):

The central scales would bear the weight of the beam, and the other scales would resist the downward movement of one end of it, causing it to turn with the central scales as a pivot. The measurements shown on each of the scales would depend on the detailed arrangements of the experiment, and specifically on how easily the beam could pivot on the central scales (was it sitting on a knife edge on the scales or on a wide plate) and how close the other scales were to bearing the weight at the exact end-point of the beam.

If you imagine the beam perfectly balanced on a knife edge on the central scales, you would be able to raise one end of it with hardly any effort.

Comment: The scales are the exact same height, so the beam is perfectly level. There is no pivot that's why I said the scales are the exact same height, and they are the same type of scale, there's no pivoting, the beam is making equal contact with both scales, but one scale is in the center of the beam and the other at one end.